# Handle error in jQuery.ajax() when something doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file with a form that is sent using jQuery.ajax(). The problem that I have if the email is not sent and the error message is not shown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
                email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                msg: $('input[name="msg"]').val()
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(responseText) {
                $('#result').css('background', 'green');
            },
            error: function(responseText) {
                $('#result').css('background', 'red');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

As the email is not sent the error not shows anything but the success yes. So, I change my mail.php code for that other code.

```
<?php
    if(2 > 4) {
        true;
    } else {
        false;
    }
?>
```

When I press the button, the success action stills working and I don't know why.

Comment: what you want to do with `2 > 4` ?

Comment: @GauravVashishtha  returns false

Comment: Why dont you validate the email from the js itself, before making ajax call to mail.php. i`m seriously not getting what you have done in php, the one which u have posted here. it would be better if you can add the complete function/code which is processing the ajax call in mail.php

Comment: then you need to echo the true and false. I am posting the code check that.

Comment: @roasted then OP can try by direct return the false.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha ya sure, i've stopped to try to understand some user code logic long time ago ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error function will not trigger unless jQuery fails to connect to your php file, in this case you would wan't to handle your own errors, first off what does this do?

```
if(2 > 4) {
    true;
} else {
    false;
}
```

this would not send anything back to jQuery i recommend the following

```
if(2 > 4) {
   echo 'true';
} else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

then in your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
                email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                msg: $('input[name="msg"]').val()
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                if(result === 'true') {
                   $('#result').css('background', 'green');
                } else {
                  $('#result').css('background', 'red');
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error)
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The error callback is only triggered if the ajax call fails, not if the PHP mail function fails, and not if you return false, that would be a success as you received something back from the server (the string "false").

To catch errors like that you can either trigger an error from PHP or just catch it in the success handler:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (!data || $.trim(data) == 'false') {
        $('#result').css('background', 'red');
    }else{
        $('#result').css('background', 'green');
    }
},
```

and PHP

```
<?php
    echo 2>4 ? 'true' : 'false';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the error function & make changes to your success function

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
                email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                msg: $('input[name="msg"]').val()
            },
            cache: false,
success: function(responseText) {
                if(responseText)$('#result').css('background', 'green');
                else $('#result').css('background', 'red');
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your both cases, the success callback is fired:

```
success: function(responseText) {
                if(!!responseText)  //!! convert string to boolean
                   $('#result').css('background', 'green');
                else
                   $('#result').css('background', 'red');
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

First in mail.php file echo that you want to return:

```
<?php
    if(2 > 4) {
      echo "true";
    } else {
       echo "false";
    }
?>
```

And then in success function do that:

```
       success: function(responseText) {
           if(responseText) {
            $('#result').css('background', 'green');
           } else {
            $('#result').css('background', 'red');
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the version of the jquery you are using. If its 1.9 then you can handle it using the done, fail and always function

For 1.9

```
var request = $.ajax({
url: "mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
                email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                msg: $('input[name="msg"]').val()
    }

});

request.done(function(e){
//GET THE STATUS FOR THE EMAIL FROM THE PHP SCRIPT
//ASSUMPTION THAT FETCHING e=1/0 - 1 - Success, 0 - Failure
if(parseInt(e))
{
$("#result").css("background","green");
}
else
{
$("#result").css("background","red");
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your php script doesn't return anything. For instance, if you eliminate all javascript from your html page, and your form's action attribute specifies myphp.php, and myphp.php looks like this:

```
<?php

$html = "<html><head></head><body><div>Hello world.</div></body></html>";

?>
```

What will be displayed after you click on the form's submit button?

2) The error function is called if the request *fails*.  Getting a response of nothing or false from your php script is not a failure of the request.  A successful request means that the browser sent out a request, the server received the request, the server caused your php script to execute, and the server sent back the results of your php script as a response.  A request fails if the server is too busy to respond to the request, the server crashes while handling your request, you request a file that doesn't exist, etc.